# Services Entity REST Application - Update (via put) Field Collection Data

Tags: services, entities, 8

I am trying to figure out what the format and required parameters are for an update request to a field collection via the [Services Module's](https://drupal.org/project/services) REST API. I have installed the [Services Entity API Module](https://drupal.org/project/services_entity) to allow interaction via Services with additional entity types.

I was able to save to a field collection when I first set everything up, using a PUT request, the CSRF token and properly formatted JSON.

```
{"field_fivestar_value":[
      {
         "rating":"100",
         "target":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

which gave me this to access: `field_fivestar_value['und'][0]['value']` which seemed to work perfect in the past, but now it seems that something is interfering/wrong as i get a notice after submitting a PUT request that $revision_id and/or $field_name aren't set, which never happened before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that something to do with revisions is causing the problem as if I provide specific (required?) data in my PUT request it works. Working PUT request JSON:

```
{
    "field_primary_aircraft": {
        "und": [
            {
                "value": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "field_name": "field_aircraft",
    "item_id": "5929",
    "revision_id": "5929",
    "default_revision": true,
    "field_aircraft_registration": {
        "und": [
            {
                "value": "testing12355"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

That JSON plus a working CSRF token allowed me to save data back to a field collection that  is part of a users Profile2 profile.

The `revision_id` and `default_revision` were the trickiest parts to track down and supply, I don't have revisions enabled as far as I can tell also, so why this problem started suddenly I have no idea...at least it is solved and hopefully this info helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This sandbox will implement a field_collection service for services 3.x: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/graber/2141747

Work is still in progress for entity api support for field _collections here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2044833